Proving that $\forall x (0 + x = x)$ given that $\forall x (x + 0 = x)$ in Peano Arithmetic using Natural Deduction
I'm trying to prove that $\forall x (0 + x = x)$ given that $\forall x (x + 0 = x)$ in Peano Arithmetic using Natural Deduction. By the induction axiom schema
$$\forall P \left(P(0) \land \forall x (P(x) \rightarrow P(s(x))) \rightarrow \forall x P(x)\right)$$
(for every formula $P$ with one variable) I need to show that

$0+ 0 = 0$, and
$\forall x[(0 + x = x)\to (0 + s(x) = s(x))]$

The first is easy and I was able to do. For the second, I would like to do the following:
\begin{split}
\forall x( 0 + x = x) & \ \ \ \ \text{ assumption}\\
\forall x(s(0 + x) = s(x)) & \ \ \ \ \text{ by (1) i.e. the line above}\\
\forall x(s(0 + x) = 0 + s(x)) & \ \ \ \ \text{ by axiom $\forall x\forall y(s(x + y) = x + s(y))$ and $\forall$-elimination}\\
\forall x(0 + s(x)) = s(x)) & \ \ \ \ \text{ by $(2), (3)$ and transitivity of equality} 
\end{split}
The problem is that I know not how to formally derive lines $(2)$ and $(4)$, and I was hoping someone could help me out.

Edit: on a different post I asked how to prove $\forall x(x + 0 = 0 + x)$ assuming$\forall x (0+ x = x)$ among other things, so that question does not contain the current one as a subquestion i.e. I don't think it should count as a duplicate.

Why do you ask your own question twice? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4998568/how-to-prove-that-forall-x-x-0-0-x-in-peano-arithmetic-with-natural-d

In order to avoid the above misunderstanding, you can specify that what are you proving is that, assuming the axioms for sum, that is $a+0=a$, we can "reverse" the order to get $0+a=a$ without using commutativity, that is $a+b=b+a$.

Hint: First prove that $+$ is associative. Then prove that it is commutative. This works with Peano's Axioms in the language of set theory. Not sure about first-order PA with its additional restrictions.

Wrt formula 2, the Induction step, assume $0+x=x$ and apply substitution for equality: $x=y \to (f(x)=f(y))$, to get $s(0+x)=s(x)$.
Using axioms for sum and transitivity of equality you have: $0+s(x)=s(x)$.
Thus, by $(\to \text I)$ you have: $(0+x=x) \to (0+s(x)=s(x))$.
The last step needs $(\forall \text I)$ to get the result.

Check $x = 0$: namely that $0 + 0 = 0$, by definition of $0$.
Suppose that $0 + x = x$ for some $x$. Then
$$0 + s(x) = s(0 + x) = s(x),$$
where we used the induction hypothesis for the last equality. This completes the induction step.
